# How to add zlib with ExternalProject_Add to CMake project as a dependency

Tags: cmake, dependencies, dependency-management, zlib

**UPDATE:**

It's working but I don't know what happened so I will leave the question open.

---

I am trying to add zlib. For this purpose I have added the following configuration file that is included in my main `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
include(ExternalProject)

set(DEPS_BUILD  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/build)
set(DEPS_LOG    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/log)
set(DEPS_STAMP  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/stamp)
set(DEPS_TMP    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/tmp)
set(DEPS_SRC    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/src)

ExternalProject_Add(zlib
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib

    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${DEPS_SRC}/zlib
    TMP_DIR ${DEPS_TMP}/zlib
    STAMP_DIR ${DEPS_STAMP}/zlib
    LOG_DIR ${DEPS_LOG}/zlib
    BINARY_DIR ${DEPS_BUILD}/zlib
    SOURCE_DIR ${DEPS}/zlib

    INSTALL_COMMAND cmake -E echo "Skipping install step for dependency zlib"
    INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

I am using **CMake 2.21** (latest as of 9th of September 2021) and Visual Studio 2017. I have of course added **zlib** as a dependency like this:

```
add_dependencies(${MY_LIB} zlib)
```

where `MY_LIB` is the library. The `${DEPS}` variable points at a subdirectory (inside the root directory of my project) where all git submodules are currently being initialized.

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        |
        + --- CMakeLists.txt
        |
        + --- ${DEPS}
        |        |
        |        + --- dependencies.cmake
        |        | 
        |        + --- zlib git submodule
        |        | 
        |        + --- libpng git submodule
        |        | 
        |        + --- libjpeg-turbo git submodule
       ...
```

Also the reason why I define  all the variables below is mostly for structural purposes. The first time I added the `ExternalProject` stuff and ran my configuration it created a lot of directories all over the place inside my build directory. By defining specific locations I can ensure the structure I want and come in terms with:

```
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
      |
      + --- CMakeFiles
      |
      + --- CMakeCache.txt
      |
     ...
      |
      + --- deps
      |      |
      |      + --- build
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- jpeg
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- png
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- zlib
      |      |
      |      + --- src
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- jpeg
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- png
      |      |       |
      |      |       + --- zlib
      |      |
      |      |     
      |      + --- stamp
      |      |       |
      |      |      ...
      |      |
      |      + --- tmp
      |              |
      |             ... 
      |
     ...
```

I am working on and which uses **zlib**'s functionality internally. After generating the VS solution (with the **ZERO_BUILD**, **ALL_BUILD** etc. projects added to it) for VS 2017 64bit debug build I tried to build the **zlib** project just to see if it work properly but I am getting the following error:

```
Performing build step for 'zlib'
CUSTOMBUILD : error : could not load cache
```

I have successfully added **turbojpeg** to my project (with the same code) and it works without any issues. Given my previous experience with **zlib** when building 3rd party software (libs, executables) I am inclined to think that there is some configuration step missing. What that step might be is beyond me. I am also new to the `ExternalProject` module of CMake.

Comment: What is `DEPS` variable? It is used in the `SOURCE_DIR` specification. If `SOURCE_DIR` is already contained zlib sources, then why do your specify `DOWNLOAD_DIR`? This variable is for download step only.

Comment: If you are talking about `DEPS_xyz` - it's just a prefix for each variable that I will use at some point inside my dependencies cmake configuration file. I have checked inside `zlib` didn't find any variables names like this. I am specifying all this variables because - except currently for the downloading part - I actually want to use them. And at some point I might actually move completely to downloading the sources using `ExternalProject`. I think I fixed my issue in the meanwhile but I need to verify. I did some changes and tomorrow will see, which one fixed my issues.

Comment: No I mean the variable with **exact name** `DEPS`:  `SOURCE_DIR ${DEPS}/zlib`. I see settings of all other `DEPS_*` variables, but no a given one.

Comment: Ah, yes. I will add the information to my question. It's working now but I have no idea what happened. Deleted the whole build dir of my project and the cmake cache several times. :D Since the dependencies cmake configuration file is executed by the main CMakeLists.txt, this variable is defined there. It points at the subdirectory of the main projects, where all git submodules are initialiazed. So this is a partent scope variable.