# How do I add zlib via CMake?

Tags: cmake, zlib

I have a project in c++ where I need to use zlib. Because I want it to be a self contained project I have downloaded the zlib source from their GitHub, and added it in a library folder.
How can I tell cmake to use that folder as a library?

Comment: "How can I tell cmake to use that folder as a library?" - As usual, you may add other project into your one with [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) command and link with the target created by that other project. Note, that ZLIB project doesn't follow target-oriented approach, so you will need to manually add include directories. Alternatively, you may include ZLIB via ExternalProject_Add: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120924/how-to-add-zlib-with-externalproject-add-to-cmake-project-as-a-dependency.

Comment: How i understand that is that `ExternalProject_Add` would use external code, this would make it not self contained

Comment: "How i understand that is that `ExternalProject_Add` would use external code" - You may pass to the `ExternalProject_Add` not only a network address of the repository, but also a local directory, which contains ZLIB sources. Using `ExternalProject_Add` doesn't mean that your project won't be a self-contained.

Comment: it doesnt seem like i can use ExternalProject at all

Comment: Do you want to tell us why you can't use it?

Comment: when i type `ext` clion does not show it as a suggestion

Comment: Have you tried typing it out? Did you `include(ExternalProject)`?

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add` is a cmake function, not a value for a parameter

Comment: That is true. This function happens to be defined in the file `ExternalProject.cmake` which you include with the line `include(ExternalProject)`. So you need to do *two* things: include the file and call the function.

Comment: I can now call the function, how should I use it to include zlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to build and install zlib using your approach of choice (zlib includes a Makefile and a CMakeLists.txt). Ex.

```
cd <wherever you cloned zlib to>
cmake -S . -B build <other options you want> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<absolute path to where you want to install to>
cmake --build build <other options you want>
cmake --install build
```

Note that usually you can use [the `--prefix` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake--install-0) to `cmake --install`, but zlib uses some [not-so-great CMake practices](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/v1.2.13/CMakeLists.txt#L8) that prevent that from being possible, so instead, you have to set [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html).

If you are using a [multi-config generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html), make sure that the configurations you're building and installing match. You can't install something you haven't built yet. See also [the build `--config` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-config), and [the install `--config` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-install-config). Ex.

```
cd <wherever you cloned zlib to>
cmake -S . -B build <other options you want> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<absolute path to where you want to install to>
cmake --build build --config Release <other options you want>
cmake --install build --config Release
```

Depending on your and your build-users' needs, (basically, if you're going to want to always have you and your build-users clone, build, and install a specific version of zlib, you may find [the `ExternalProject` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) helpful in automating the above).

And then use `find_package` in your CMakeLists.txt. CMake provides a find module to find zlib installations: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html. Ex.

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT <where you installed zlib to>)
# set(ZLIB_USE_STATIC_LIBS YES) # uncomment if cmake_minimum_required >= 3.24 and you want to find zlibstatic instead of zlib
find_package(zlib <other arguments you want>)
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

do `set(ZLIB_ROOT ...)` if you install zlib to a directory inside your project directory. Otherwise, I advise to set this hint variable using [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) in the configuration command.

See also

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Comment: with that i get
`D:/programming/project/lib/zlib>cmake --install build`
`-- Install configuration: "Release"`
`CMake Error at build/cmake_install.cmake:99 (file):`
`  file INSTALL cannot find`
 ` "D:/programming/project/lib/zlib/build/Release/zlib.dll":`
  `File exists.`

Comment: please show the full command you used to configure the project. What generator are you using? (is it multi-config or single-config? if it's multi-config, which configuration did you build? (show your build command))

Comment: [here is my full log with output](https://pastebin.com/mTwJEPrF)

Comment: @ThunderSphun see the edit I just made. you're using visual studio- a multi-config generator, and you didn't specify the config to build or install. the default for build was `Debug`, but for install was `Release`. kind of unfortunate (I'm not sure why that happens).

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: @ThunderSphun read my edit. see the part that mentions `--config`.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this, as i have 0 experience running cmake through the command line, and i have no idea what i should enter at what stages